# Keycloak overriding ip address on event entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, backend, keycloak

Is there any way how to override ip address on event entity on keycloak database , or to persist data on event_entity on keycloak using a spi

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because right now , when a user is login , i have a default ip address , of my service (security), i want the user ip address

Comment: That sounds like your proxy configuration is not correct...? But the API gives you the method on the `EventBuilder` class: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/events/EventBuilder.html#ipAddress-java.lang.String- - I do think that you need to configure your proxies correctly though.

Comment: The ip address being set in the event is the ip address of the client setup in keycloak instead of the user ip address accessing the application in the browser. I want to log the ip address of the user instead of that of the keycloak client.